# How to add image upload to description field in product edit?

Tags: tinymce

I added tinyMCE in textarea for description field in product edit form, but image upload is not showing. When i open default editor everything is working good. What is wrong with my code?
My code:

```
        tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements: "description",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins: "inlinepopups,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
        extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
        theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
        apply_source_formatting : 'true',
        convert_urls : 'false',
        force_br_newlines : 'true',
        doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

    });
```

Thanks for help

Comment: How are you adding this code?

Comment: I added it to catalog/product/edit.phtml in design adminhtml. Code is inside window.onload()

Answer (score 0):

By default the `product description` and `short description` already have the wysiwyg enabled:

[image]

If you are wanting to add the wysiwyg to a custom field on the product then you will need to create a custom module with an observer in order to add the js and field config.

I wrote a post here http://rob3000.com/adding-wysiwyg-to-magento-form/ that goes through how to add the wysiwyg to a magento form which should point you into the right direction.